# Why decltype((i)) is reference type but decltype(i+0) is int type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am studying C++ Primer fifth edtion,and the example code really confused me.It is similar as the code below:

```
int i,&k=i;
decltype((i)) t;    //error: t must be initialized
decltype(k+0) s = 45;  //OK,s is int type
```

Why the two are expressions and  the first one is reference type but the second one is int type?

Comment: Mostly because the standard says so. Are you looking for standards quotes or motivation?

Comment: I guess [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4) is the why (and a similar example too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decltype((i));
```

Will yield a reference type since `i` is an lvalue. This is useful to determine the [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of any expression. Reproduced form [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), for parenthesized expression (emphasis mine):

> a. if the value category of expression is **xvalue**, then decltype yields
>   **T&&**;
>
> b. if the value category of expression is **lvalue**, then decltype yields
>   **T&**;
>
> c. if the value category of expression is **prvalue**, then decltype
>   yields **T**.

---

```
decltype(k+0)
```

Will yield the type of the result the `k+0` expression will evaluate to. Just as `auto val = k + 0;` would deduce `val`.